# setting to enable asking download location for each download in microsoft edge

Tags: windows-10, download, microsoft-edge

I use Microsoft edge for most of my work.
I download files many times from the internet we all do.
Now the problem is each time I need to save files in different different locations. In my settings inside edge here is how they look
[image: edge download setting screenshot]
screenshot of chrome
[image: chrome download setting]
is this same kind of thing possible for Microsoft edge that means when I download anything edge asks me each time where to save the download?

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that even with the "ask me what to do with each download" setting turned on, Edge doesn't do what it should?

Comment: yes ....edge does not do what is should do ....... my settings are as I posted above in screenshot if I have to look some where else or I missed some thing then let me know

Comment: As you can see in the discussion below the answer, either me or John are misunderstanding your problem. Can you please confirm one way or another? In other words, can you please confirm whether or not Edge is asking *where* to download the file, as it should be doing with that setting ON?

Comment: John has misunderstood in fact his answer is totally wrong,my program deviates from normal behavior hence I have to ask this silly question here. You have understood the problem correctly that setting is on but edge is not asking where to download the file each time (that is why I gave google chrome screenshot) as it should be doing with that setting ON.

Comment: I confirmed in Edge that Edge (for me) asks to Save / Save As and pauses allowing me put the file where I need.  I will delete my answer as I posted what Edge does and is supposed to do

Comment: @John yes I understand your point my question is that it is not working as it should work so I need to check something and what is that something I do not know.

Comment: Try (in Settings, Apps) to both Repair and Reset Edge. That is a corrective procedure for Edge

Comment: Where is Settings Apps location

Comment: Windows 10, Start, Settings, then click on Apps on the window that comes up. Scroll down for Microsoft Edge, click on advanced settings and do repair and reset (both). Close out, restart and test.

Comment: @john your method of repair has worked. This gave me desired result. Thanks

Comment: If I reopen my question, and add the repair step, will you give me credit for it

Comment: Yes I will you can answer I will accept

Comment: I did add the answer to my first answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Go to Edge Settings, and below the Download Location, enable "Ask me what to do with each download"  Edge always asks me.

Also you can go the Start, Settings, Apps, and scroll down for Microsoft Edge and then Repair and Reset it (both things). That may make the setting work for you

Comment: But according to the last OP's comment, that setting is already on but Edge doesn't ask for the location as it should.

Comment: It asks you if you wish to save the file. No browser has a location for each file (hundreds of files over time), just IF you wish to save the file. From there, you can adjust the location (in any browser)

Comment: It's possible that I'm misunderstanding the question/problem but it's more likely you're the one misunderstanding it. I asked for confirmation about it and apparently, in OP's case, even with that setting turned ON it doesn't ask *where* to download the file, the whole and only point of that setting.

Comment: Let  us see what the OP wishes to do.  Edge, Chrome and other browsers can be made to ask if you wish to download. There is, however, just one download location that can be set. That is my understanding of the issue

Comment: Already asked for confirmation commenting in the question. My understanding is that their other browsers are behaving correctly - ask where to download each new file - but Edge is  not, in spite of the settings suggesting it should do just that. I don't understand how this question would make sense otherwise but it wouldn't be a first (if you know what I mean ;))

Comment: My Edge asks where to save the file.  I used the setting to ask each time.

Comment: Yes, yours is working as expected but I think OP's isn't.

Comment: So, confirmed, It's time to delete this answer because it isn't helpful as it merely states what should be happening whereas the question is about it doing the opposite. Don't you agree?

Comment: Asking "what to do" with a download (which Edge does) is NOT the same as asking "where to download" (which Edge does not do without further user action).