# Microsoft Edge save as - straight to download location explorer window

Tags: microsoft-edge

This is a super nitpick, and is not the same as [setting to enable asking download location for each download in microsoft edge](https://superuser.com/questions/1510534/setting-to-enable-asking-download-location-for-each-download-in-microsoft-edge) --

When I save an image, Edge displays a little question at the bottom, "What do you want to do with ? {Open} {Save as}"

When I save an image in Chrome, I am directly presented with the explorer save-as dialog window for my download location.

I download hundreds of images and so I've been needing to reduce muscle movement as much as possible. To that effect, I've been using "Double-click Image Downloader" with great success. I replace having the extra process of right-clicking, moving, and clicking with a single click on the top-left corner.

However, now in Edge, I have to click, move from the top of the screen, to the bottom of the screen, click save-as, and move back to the top of the screen.

This may seem innocuous, but when downloading hundreds of images by hand --- it becomes a big deal.

Does anyone know how to bypass the question and present the save-as location dialog box immediately?

[image: chrome-save-as]

[image: edge-save-as]

Comment: there used to be a setting which did exactly what you want, but it was removed a while ago :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm "using" MS Edge Chromium version 87.*

If you go to the download settings, there is an on/off switch that will allow to skip the ask what you want with the file.

In your browser, navigate to: edge://settings/downloads

[image]

Comment: Presumably, the OP wants to have the "save as" dialog open automatically, not have everything saved to the Downloads or other folder automatically. It seems Edge has no such setting.

Comment: That's correct. I'm looking for the dialog to automatically open. I already have this setting checked in the Edge settings, but the aptly named option asks me before showing the location window.

Comment: Well, having a good bit of experience doing bulk manual operations, and making them as simple and "low-work" as possible. My best approach would be to bulk save into the downloads or other bulk directory during my manual webscrape session, then put them where I want them after they have been downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the default download folder to a location that edge can't write to, it'll display a Save As dialog every time.

1. Create a new folder
2. In edge://settings/downloads, set the download Location to this folder
3. Disable the "Ask me what to do with each download" option
4. Remove your write permissions from this folder

- windows: right click the folder, select "Properties...", go to the "Security" tab, click "Edit...", check the second box next to "Write", then click "OK" etc.
  [image: screenshot]
- linux, etc.: set the folder permissions with `chmod u-w foldername`